# Android Bluetooth Permission Variable Issue

Tags: android, android-studio, android-permissions

**error: cannot find symbol
android.Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT
^
symbol:   variable BLUETOOTH_CONNECT
location: class permission**

I tried both **android.Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT and Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT** same error on both

Am using
compileSdkVersion 31
buildToolsVersion '31.0.3'

Comment: I resolved the issue by updating the Gradle version from  classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10' to classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1'.